# How to fill the matrix with values from other matrix matching rows and columns?

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to make a new matrix using values from other matrix with R. I'm trying to match the names of rows and columns while importing the values. This is what what trying to do:

I have two matrices;

```
     X1  X2  X3  X4
 X1   0   9   8   0
 X2   1   2   3   5
 X4   6   1   2   4

     X1  X2  X3  X4
 X1  NA  NA  NA  NA   
 X2  NA  NA  NA  NA   
 X3  NA  NA  NA  NA   
 X4  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

I want to do

```
     X1  X2  X3  X4
 X1   0   9   8   0   
 X2   1   2   3   5
 X3  NA  NA  NA  NA   
 X4   6   1   2   4
```

These matrices are just simple examples of my dataset, my real data is more complicated.

Many thanks,

Comment: No, I what I meant is that it is much bigger :). Every value is numerical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

checking for rownames and colnames matches in both matrices will prevent `subscript out of bounds` error. See below.

```
mat2[rownames(mat2) %in% rownames(mat1), 
     colnames(mat2) %in% colnames(mat1)] <- mat1[rownames(mat1) %in% rownames(mat2), 
                                                 colnames(mat1) %in% colnames(mat2)] 
mat2
#    X1 X2 X3 X4
# X1  0  9  8  0
# X2  1  2  3  5
# X3 NA NA NA NA
# X4  6  1  2  4
```

Data:

```
mat1 <- read.table(text = '    X1  X2  X3  X4
 X1   0   9   8   0
                   X2   1   2   3   5
                   X4   6   1   2   4', header = TRUE)

mat1 <- as.matrix(mat1)
mat2 <- matrix(NA, nrow = 4, ncol = 4, dimnames = list(paste0("X", 1:4),
                                                       paste0("X", 1:4)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question you can do this:

```
# Building your matrices
mat1 <- matrix(runif(12), nrow = 3, ncol = 4)
mat2 <- matrix(NA, nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
labs <- paste0("x", 1:4)
colnames(mat1) <- colnames(mat2) <- labs
rownames(mat2) <- labs
rownames(mat1) <- labs[c(1:2, 4)]

# 
rows <- sort(unique(c(rownames(mat1), rownames(mat2))))
result <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(rows), ncol = ncol(mat1))
result[match(rownames(mat1), rows), ] <- mat1
```

Comment: Please check if your code will work, if the `mat2` is `mat2 <- matrix(NA, nrow = 4, ncol = 4, dimnames = list(paste0("X", 5:8),
                                                       paste0("X", 5:8)))`